# submit spark job from java code and get java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, submit

I want to submit spark job to yarn cluster, and I get the reference from  "https://github.com/mahmoudparsian/data-algorithms-book/blob/master/misc/how-to-submit-spark-job-to-yarn-from-java-code.md".

Here is my code:

```
package learn.spark;

import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

public class SubmitJob {

public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception {

    String[] args = new String[] {

        "--jar", "lib/spark-examples-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar",
        "--class", "org.apache.spark.examples.mllib.JavaKMeans",
        "--num-executors", "32",
        "--executor-cores", "4",
        "--executor-memory", "16G", 
        "--driver-memory", "8G",    
        "--addJars", "./lib/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar",

        "--arg", "/data/kmeans_data.txt",
        "--arg", "5",
        "--arg", "9"    
    };

    Configuration config = new Configuration();

    System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();

    ClientArguments cArgs = new ClientArguments(args, sparkConf); 

    Client client = new Client(cArgs, config, sparkConf); 

    client.run(); 
}
}
```

I compile the source and jar. running the program by the follow cmd:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:./lib/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar: -jar learn.spark.SubmitJob.jar
```

Unluckly, I got the follow error:
[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlvcc.png)

I can't understand the problem, or How can I submit a spark job to yarn cluster? 
Is there a better way?

Comment: I find another example, but the code still confuses me. The ClientArguments used in my previous code right, but in this link occurs error when I try. I check the spark source, and I get private[deploy] class ClientArguments(args: Array[String]). Why there are different? [another example](https://github.com/sequenceiq/sequenceiq-samples/blob/master/spark-submit/spark-submit-runner/src/main/scala/com/sequenceiq/spark/SparkRunner.scala)

Comment: change theorg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit and